# Are there situations when it is logical to include the today's value in a history paper?

Tags: methodology, history

I am writing some papers in History, 16th and 17th Centuries, where dollar amounts from that time came up, example:

- profit margins traders were making selling goods on a trail
- taxes/fees they were paying on the trail
- how much the local government was collecting annually on the trail

I'm not sure if it is meaningful to convert the amount to present-day values [using a converter like this](https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/) and present them in parenthesis next to the then-amount. In my case, $500 then turned to $15000 today.

Is there any meaning to ever provide readers with present-day values of the dollar amounts? What are some situations where that is meaningful to readers?

Comment: I find that such conversions from even the 1960's into todays dollars often seem off - the whole structure of the economy has changed in 50 years, much less 500. How much would you pay for a beaver skin hat today? So, in an academic context I would avoid such conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course there are such situations. The price of an acre of land was x then. That is equivalent to y*x now.

But for the example you have given, it seems like the numbers relative to each other are more meaningful that their relation to today's numbers. A 50% tax rate is meaningful in any era. It is probably similar for profit margins. There might be exceptions, but ask what is the relevance of the comparison first. Absolute numbers are hard to interpret, but rates normally are not unless you are trying to, for example, discuss exploitive governments in some era.

Answer (score 2):

In the field of history, it is often meaningful to convey the context of that time to the present reader, and it's not all that rare for historians to use conversion tools to explain certain monetary amounts in today's currency.

What needs to be kept in mind, is that such conversions are only acceptable as a brief aside or a quick remark, that is, as a small service provided to the reader. Except in cases where economic historians have developed relatively robust or complex tools for analyzing economic data from various periods, historians in general should not be relying on conversion tools for making definitive research statements as the core argument of their academic papers.

Therefore, in your case, I would not try to use conversion rates for all of the points that you mentioned. Choose one or two points at most where you feel that it makes particular sense to convey this contextual information to the reader, and keep it brief. For example, to make it clear to present readers how emotionally painful a certain tax hike would have been felt by the population of that time, and how this could become one of the causes for popular uprisings. Another example would be to convey the depth of economic inequality between the average people in the rich neighborhoods of a city, and poor communities in another neighborhood.